# Separate line where can be more character in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to cut these line

> ```
> John Smith !! NewYork ! 01123 ! 3012-1-315-2164
> Alexander Goblin -- WA ------ 9752 - 53-76-132-310
> Bittner Albin    Cered   3123    26-1-278-127
> ```

There can be - ! \t between the words 
I tried like below, but It's not working

```
while(<FILE>) {
        if($_=~m/(\w+\s\w+)((\t) | (\s!+\s) | (\s-+\s))(\w+)((\t) | (\s!+\s) | (\s-+\s)(\d+)((\t) | (\s!+\s) | (\s-
                (\d\d-\d\d-\d+-\d+)/){
                        print $1."\n";
        }
}
```

I think this is the problem : `((\t) | (\s!+\s) | (\s-+\s))`

Comment: All the whitespace in a regex is literal (unless you have `/x`). You probably mean `|` without spaces around it.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: first $1 name, second $2 location, $3 zipcode, $4 phonenumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract the first two words, you can use

```
if (m/(\w+\s+\w+)/) {
    print "$1\n";
}
```

If you want to split those lines to its field, you can use

```
my @field = split /\s+!+\s+ | \s+-+\s+ | \t+ /x;
```

Here is the full example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my @record;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    if (m/(\w+\s+\w+)/) {
        print "$1\n";
    }

    my @field = split /\s+!+\s+ | \s+-+\s+ | \t+ /x;
    push @record, \@field;
}

print Dumper(\@record);

__DATA__
John Smith !! NewYork ! 01123 ! 3012-1-315-2164
Alexander Goblin -- WA ------ 9752 - 53-76-132-310
Bittner Albin   Cered   3123    26-1-278-127
```

---

Note: the separator of the last line in the above code is `\t`, not three/four spaces.

---

Output of the above program:

```
$ perl t.pl 
John Smith
Alexander Goblin
Bittner Albin
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'John Smith',
            'NewYork',
            '01123',
            '3012-1-315-2164'
          ],
          [
            'Alexander Goblin',
            'WA',
            '9752',
            '53-76-132-310'
          ],
          [
            'Bittner Albin',
            'Cered',
            '3123',
            '26-1-278-127'
          ]
        ];
```

Comment: thanx i needed this one: \s+!+\s+ | \s+-+\s+ | \t+